# Is it possible to use 'pipe' for batches of tokenized documents in Spacy?

Tags: spacy

Based on this link:
[Is it possible to use spacy with already tokenized input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53594690/is-it-possible-to-use-spacy-with-already-tokenized-input)

I can get Spacy to take tokenized doc as input and process the doc further. And the code is below:

```
def nlp_process(self, token_tuple):
   # token_tuple = ("This is a test", ['This','is','a','test'])
    doc = Doc(self.nlp.vocab, words=token_tuple[1])
    for name, proc in self.nlp.pipeline:
      doc = proc(doc)

   return doc
```

This works well for single input. What about if I want to process docs in batch mode by using nlp.pipe() function? Something like:

```
   nlp_docs = self.nlp.pipe(texts)
```

The pipe takes a list of raw text. How to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to set up a tokenizer-less pipeline in spacy. One option is to call each pipeline component individually after creating the docs:

```py
for pipe_name in nlp.pipe_names:
    docs = nlp.get_pipe(pipe_name).pipe(docs)
```

Or another equivalent:

```py
for pipe_name, pipe in nlp.pipeline:
    docs = pipe.pipe(docs)
```

If you're not enabling multiprocessing, this will be as efficient as using `nlp.pipe()` because this is also more or less what `nlp.pipe()` does underneath.

Another alternative is to create your own replacement tokenizer that accepts either `List[str]` or `Doc` inputs and replace `nlp.tokenizer` with this custom tokenizer. Then you can call `nlp.pipe()` as usual. The simplest version of this with `List[str]` input would look like this:

```
from spacy.tokens import Doc

class CustomTokenizer(DummyTokenizer):
    def __init__(self, vocab):
        self.vocab = vocab

    def __call__(self, words):
        return Doc(self.vocab, words=words)

nlp.tokenizer = CustomTokenizer(nlp.vocab)
doc = nlp(["This", "is", "a", "sentence", "."])
```

This example and some related examples and discussion are here: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/5399

Comment: The first option also ran into an issue. The neural network's predict reports a 'no doc attribute' error in   ''doc.doc'.

Comment: Regarding 'Then you can call nlp.pipe() as usual': if I use the 'CustomTokenizer' option, when I use nlp.pipe(), would the input of pipe is a list of a list of tokens? inputs = [['This', 'is', 'test'], ['This', 'was', 'test']]? This won't work, since the CustomToeknizer's input is a list of words, not list of list of words.

Comment: The `docs` argument for `pipe.pipe()` is `List[Doc]`. If you use `nlp.pipe()` with the custom tokenizer then you provide `List[List[str]]`, if you use `nlp()`, then `List[str]` as in the example above.